# Global Colosseum: What's the difference between tournament and random match?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

I tried out the tournament feature for the first time last night and it wasn't really what I expected. There was no ladder, no indication of where in the tournament you are or what the context of the "tournament" is.

The tournament had 17 people at the time. I won 5 matches, but was still prompted to search for the next battle. Really, I don't see any difference between this and a random match.

Can anyone fill me in on the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tournament play, it will register how many wins you get during the period of validity of the tournament (displayed on the popup when you hover it). You can then compete with other players in the leaderboard.

Random matches are more casual. It will track your total win ratio but nothing more.

Comment: I did notice that. Still, there HAS to be more to it, right? By definition, this does not fit the concept of a "tournament".